# How can I call another element from an array with the same name?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, arraylist

I'm relatively new to JavaScript / React.js. I have a random API from which I want to read an item (in this example an email adress).

What if the array has more emails for different users?

In that case, how can I call that specific email, let's say 2nd and 5th. What is the syntax for that?

Code is given bellow:

```
   import {useState,useEffect} from 'react';

function App(){

  const url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/';

  const [information,setInformation]=useState([]);
  
  async function getData(){
    const resp = await fetch(url);
    const data = await resp.json();
    console.log(data);
    const [item]=data.results;
    setInformation(item);
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    getData();
  },[])

  return(
    <>
      {information.email}
    </>
  )
}
export default App;
```

Comment: What will be the format of data in case of more than one email? Comma separated string or array?

Comment: Comma separated string in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are getting the data as an array, of the format

> email: ["a@gmail.com", "b@gmail.com"]

You can map them as :

```
export default function App() {
  let information = { email: ["a@gmail.com", "b@gmail.com"] };
  return (
    <ul>
      {information.email.map((item, i) => (
        <li key={i}>{item}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Or to display a particular email, say of 1st location, access them as:

```
   <>
      {information.email[1]}
    </>
```

Comment: Will this work for these API's (example):
authors[
 {
 author: ...
 email: ...
 },
 {
 author: ...
 email: ...
 }
 ...
]

Comment: @FraneCal Yes, provided the data of `email` is in array format.